# Cordova/PhoneGap websql vs native sqlite plugin

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

Using Apache Cordova / Adobe PhoneGap to develop an app usually also means using a DB.
Cordova offers out of the box WebSQL thanks to the embedded webview.

Another option would be to use a native [Cordova-SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin).

Can someone provide pros/cons of the two options?
I can thinks at least of the following dimensions:

- which is more stable / complete / bug free ?
- which is more consistant across the platforms ?
- which is faster (provide links to data if you have any!!!) ?